# Is it possible to reverse the layers of a convolutional neural network?

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

From my understanding typically a convolutional neural network has a matrix (e.g. an image) as input and output is either an integer or a vector of integers in regression and in classification a number of different classes.

My question is, is it possible to reverse the layers of a CNN, e.g. first you have a class like “dog” and then the same layers, but reversed, and output is a matrix (e.g. an image)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try [ai.se] for theoretical AI questions. (I have absolutely no idea how this question is supposed to be a Python question, since CNNs can be implemented in any Turing-complete programming language.)

Answer (score 0):

Typically a neural network extract information from information rich images to descend to a more semantic answer such as 'this is a dog', or a % of 'dogness'.
This is not bijective as an infinite number of pictures could result in a dog information, so starting from the end to create an image would be difficult / impossible.

However you can perform image modifications until your network gives you a high dogness value.